# VS Code: Create file inside the current directory of the editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Is it possible to create a new file inside the same folder as the file that is active in the editor by the time the keyboard shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> for `explorer.newFile` is hit?

I can tell if it's the correct folder by looking at the breadcrumbs and mostly have the file explorer toggled off. The command, however, seems to create a file inside the last folder opened or focused by the file explorer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by overloading that `explorer.newFile` command's default keybinding to run a task instead.  Here is the keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+n",
  "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
  "args": "newFile",
  "when": "editorFocus"  // must have an editor focused
},
```

And the task (in tasks.json):

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",

  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "newFile",

      "command": "touch '${fileDirname}/${input:fileName}' && code '${fileDirname}/${input:fileName}'",

      "type": "shell",
      "problemMatcher": [],
    },
   ],

  "inputs": [
    {
      "type": "promptString",
      "id": "fileName",
      "description": "Complete my file name.",
      "default": "new file name"
    }
  ]
}
```

That will create a file in the same directory as the active editor's directory - it will ask you for the filename - and then open it.

I used the bash command `touch` to create the file (if it doesn't already exist), if you are using a different shell you will need the equivalent of `touch`.

Comment: Thank you! This does help but I can't quite accept the answer as there are a few minor problems.

1. It uses the task input API instead of showing the folder and letting me type there.

2. Tasks seem to be much slower. I'm on a pretty good desktop computer and it still took 3-4 seconds for the prompt to open.

3. It opens the terminal in VSCode as the shell command is executed

4. It doesn't work for Linux and Windows as we have to adjust the path for both platforms.